# jQuery-File-Upload send error

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I want to upload a file as soon as it is added to input. I use code like this

```
<form>
    <input id="MyInput" type="file">
</form>

<script>
    $('#MyInput').fileupload({
        url: '/Upload',
        change: function() {
            $('#MyInput').fileupload('send', {})
                .success(function() { console.log('success') })
                .error(function() { console.log('error') });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I see that jQuery-File-Upload send a request with files from the queue and server returns 200 OK. But the promise rejects and I have an 'error' in console.

I look inside the plugin code and see that in this case it returns a promise that always rejects. You should pass a fileInput or files as 'send' parameter to get a resolvable promise. But then files will be duplicated.

How can I get resolved promise with server response?